# Default property for class in delphi 7

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I'd like to ask on how to set default property in a delphi 7 class? So it can be accesed by just writing >> class := '..'; << that's if the default property set to text. so we dont have to write class.text := '..';

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. In your comments to answers, you have indicated some extra information (that you want a Delphi example similar to some VB code). I think you should edit your question, put both some VB example that works, and some Delphi mockup (that does not necessarily work) to show us what you are really after. Also re-tag your question for the VB version (VB6, VB.NET, etc) you use as a background.

Comment: For example Read is class which have Display and Say properties (boolean data type). And 'say' is the default property for 'Read' class, in vb if you want to access 'say' we can write class = true it is the same with writing read.say = true. What i ask is if we can make some property as default property for a class like above? (the vb part is not important as what i ask is if delphi 7 can do that? and how to that if it can?)

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that because it leads to ambiguous situation.

For example, you have a class:

```
type
  TMyClass = class
  public
    property MyProperty: TMyClass read FMyProperty; default;
  end;
var
  a, b : TMyClass;

begin
  // ...
  a := b; // Do we assign to a or to MyProperty
  // ...
end;
```

It could have worked for other (basic) types but its still confusing. Besides, its just a few extra characters to type.

Comment: No, its not like that. What i mean is how TAdoQuery works, for example, QRY: TAdoquery, you want to access value for each fields you have, you can just write QRY['field_name'] which leads to Qry.fieldByName('field_name'). Now I want to change that default property to something else. Can we do that?

Comment: You're right, using default keyword is working, property MyProperty: TMyClass read FMyProperty; default;... Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you can't. A class can have an array default property or an ordinal-type default property but not a string.

Comment: Can we really have an ordinal default property?

Comment: @Sertac - I was about to ask that - I assume he is referring to the storage specifier. Note taht later Delphi version can have more than one default array property, as long as they have different signatures, eg: `property ByName[AName: string]...;default` and `property ByIndex[AIndex: Integer]...;default`

Comment: @Gerry - I didn't know about multiple default properties, nice.. A 'string' index?.. Oh! it works... No one has told me that. Thanks Gerry, you've been really helpful!

Comment: It is *very* new afaict: Doesn't work in D2007, I think it was in D2009. However string indexes have been around forever - refer     TStrings.Values

Comment: What i mean is in visual basic you can access default property by calling the class. Some example, property A: string read FA write FA; this property is assigned default in the class (not default value). So if we just call the class we can get the value from property A. And we can set the value for Class.A by just call its class, Class := 'A'; String is just an example, you can use other delphi data type. Is that possible in delphi?

Comment: 'very new'?! I've been doing this since Delphi 5 if I recall correctly

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is a custom Variant type:
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Variants.TCustomVariantType